# Short format for durations using MomentJS?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Is there any easy way to format a duration  differently depending on how long it is?
The `Humanize` sort of does this. but AFAIK, the smallest unit there is "a few seconds"

I would like to round it off to nearest time unit.
e.g. if the duration is less than 1 sec, then format it as MS, if it is less than 1 min, format it as seconds, etc.

Is my only option to check how big/small the duration is myself?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is an easy way to do this using MomentJS.

But if you can use different library, [HumanizeDuration.js](https://github.com/EvanHahn/HumanizeDuration.js) might be a better tool:

```
humanizeDuration(999, {
  units: ['y', 'mo', 'w', 'd', 'h', 'm', 's', 'ms'],
  largest: 1
});
// "999 milliseconds"

humanizeDuration(1234, {
  units: ['y', 'mo', 'w', 'd', 'h', 'm', 's', 'ms'],
  largest: 1
});
// "1 second"
```

The value of `largest` specifies how many units with a value different than `0` you want to display.